# site pages are not showing up on the community builder

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am using Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce. I am following the below steps

- Created Site.com page
- Clicking on Community Builder

It is giving error

[image]

And when i added the default login page as home page in configuration settings it is showing up in community builder. I don't no where I am doing mistake Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

in Site.com studio, you need to assign a home page through your site configuration:

[image]

hence the error "We cant find a valid home page for this community..."

the page needs to be a valid site page (all valid site pages will appear in the dropdown for selecting the pages under default pages)

Answer (score 0):

Try going to Setup > Communities > All Communities, and click **Manage** next to the community you're building. From there, go to Administration > Pages, then click "Go to Site.com Studio" (screenshot below).

[image: Go to Site.com Studio]

Comment: I did the above steps but it is giving same error

Comment: Sounds like maybe it's a bug. Have you tried creating a new community? And have you logged a case with Salesforce Support?

Comment: When I used Napili Template i was able to go to the community builder. But anyhow now i am not using community builder instead building a new Vf page

Comment: You need to click on the force.com link on the left in the image. You can select a homepage from there.